# Компилятор не видит реализацию функций C++

Tags: c++, linux, g++

Пытался собрать проект из основного main.cpp, а также заголовочного funcs.hpp и его реализации funcs.cpp.

Код (Пример из документации к vs):

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "funcs.hpp"

using namespace std;

void PlayGames()
{
    Cardgame bridge(4);
    Cardgame blackjack(8);
    Cardgame solitaire(1);
    Cardgame poker(5);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    PlayGames();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

funcs.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "funcs.hpp"

using namespace std;

int Cardgame::totalParticipants = 0;

Cardgame::Cardgame(int players)
    : players(players)
{
    totalParticipants += players;
    cout << players << " players have started a new game.  There are now "
         << totalParticipants << " players in total." << endl;
}

Cardgame::~Cardgame()
{
}
```

funcs.hpp

```
#pragma once

class Cardgame
{
    int players;
    static int totalParticipants;
public:
    Cardgame(int players);
    ~Cardgame(void);
    static int GetParticipants() { return totalParticipants; }
};
```

Компилятор выдаёт:
    g++ -g main.cpp -o CardGame
    /tmp/ccg6sGIc.o: In function `PlayGames()':
    main.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to`Cardgame::Cardgame(int)'
    main.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `Cardgame::Cardgame(int)'
    main.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to`Cardgame::Cardgame(int)'
    main.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `Cardgame::Cardgame(int)'
    main.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to`Cardgame::~Cardgame()'
    main.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `Cardgame::~Cardgame()'
    main.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to`Cardgame::~Cardgame()'
    main.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `Cardgame::~Cardgame()'
    main.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to`Cardgame::~Cardgame()'
    /tmp/ccg6sGIc.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xba): more undefined references to `Cardgame::~Cardgame()' follow
    /tmp/ccg6sGIc.o: In function`__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
    main.cpp:(.text+0x120): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
    main.cpp:(.text+0x135): undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
    /tmp/ccg6sGIc.o:(.data.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Возможно стоит добавить какие-нибудь ключи при компиляции?

Comment: Ну так вы же компилируете только main.cpp. Как же компилятор сможет найти эти функции, если они сидят в funcs.cpp? Компилятор ничего не знает про funcs.cpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно в команде все .cpp файлы указать: `g++ -g main.cpp funcs.cpp -o CardGame`

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите скомпилировать все сразу, то в командной строке компилятора надо сразу указывать *все* `.cpp` файлы, как указано в ответе @HolyBlackCat.

Если же вы хотите компилировать `.cpp` файлы по одному, то вам нужно подавлять работу линкера при компиляции отдельных `.cpp` файлов. А линковку выполнять только когда уже все `.cpp` файлы скомпилированы,

```
g++ -g main.cpp -с
g++ -g funcs.cpp -с
g++ -g main.o funcs.o -o CardGame
```