# Как собрать несколько .с файлов в терминале?

Tags: c, gcc

я просто эти три .с файла вызываю по очереди, но при вызове каждого файла выскакивает одна ошибка : collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сначала надо скомпилировать каждый отдельно `gcc -c laba_linux.c -o laba_linux.o` получаться объектные файлы. А потом собрать их вместе `gcc laba_linux.o main.o ... -o result_program -lncurses`

Comment: `gcc -o main.exe file1.c file2.c ...`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852312/182825